# JDBC DataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource

When I run the following code on one machine I get tomcat implementation of `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource` and when I run it on another machine I get apache commons implementations of `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` (which obviously results in `ClassCastException`). Just wondering why no change in code and `context.xml` would result in returning two different implementations of DataSource?

```
Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
return (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/dbName");
```

Comment: Have you checked the jar files containing these classes?

Comment: Could it be as simple as a classpath issue? Are both tomcat servers started with the SAME startup script? Are the wars exactly-the-same-file on both servers? Are both server configurations the same?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, @JSS what am I checking in their jar files? @Corlettk I am not sure what you mean by classpath issue, startsup script is different in terms of memory allocation and yeah war is same. Can you plz be a bit more specific.

Comment: Re Classpath: they meant the same jar file names with the same sizes and timestamps in your Tomcat common/lib, server/lib and shared/lib directories. Other than that check that you actually run on the same Tomcat version.

Comment: I don't quite understand when and why you get a `ClassCastException`. Both are just `java.sql.DataSource` implementations, right? Just declare them as such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are not including DBCP inside your war. So it's using whatever DataSource is configured in Tomcat. You're probably using two different versions of Tomcat, or at least they have been configured differently; one must have commons-dbcp.jar and the other one has tomcat-dbcp.jar.